# Java Authentication on server

Tags: java, sql

I have such a small problem. I have this code:

```
 public Server()
       try {
          ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
          System.out.println("Server has been launched.");
          connection = new DBconnection();
          connection.startConnection();
          System.out.println("Succesfully connected to database!");
      } catch(IOException IOe) { 
          System.out.println("Can not establish server!");
          System.exit(-1);
      } 
        }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
                Server server = new Server();
        }

        public boolean login(String username, String password)
        {
            /*
            Verifying logins.
            - Returns TRUE if the username and password are correct
            - else FALSE
            */ 
            return true;
        }

        public String getSaveGame(User user)
        {
            String saveData = "";
            /*
             It downloads the saved position from the server.
            */
            return saveData;
        }

        public void uploadSaveGame(String saveData)
        {
            /*
            Uploads the saved position
            */
        }
```

And I do not know how to do it. The application should connect to an existing database and download some data.

Could you please write the first method to find out how this is done? Or some tutorial where it should be. Do those methods I have to write sql queries?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: go through jdbc in java you will get lot of db connectivity code.

Comment: Okay, could you please explain this in some detail? Or show me it on my code would be the best

Comment: I do not know how to authenticate users first